# Nice design for Textarea in forms in bootstrap?

Tags: css, textarea

Arent there any CSS stylings for textarea in CSS bootstrap?

`<input type="text" >` has various classes that can be applied to it, but nothing for textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it a class of `.form-control` in a form which gives it the 'bootstrap' look like other inputs.

Example:

```
<textarea class='form-control'>Test</textarea>
```

You can however still add some classes to the parent `div`:

```
has-warning
has-error
has-success
```

Most styling classes you can give an `input`'s parent, you can give to a `textarea`'s. However, classes applied to `textarea`'s parents like `has-feedback` will have varied results.

Example: [<kbd>bootply</kbd>](http://www.bootply.com/112410)